# Django Aggregate is Repeating Sum in Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am aggregating the sum of a column in my view with:

```
total_sessions = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('sessions')).get('sessions__sum', 0)
```

and displaying in my template as:

```
{{ total_sessions }}
```

but when I look at the page in the browser it repeats the sum several times - see screenshot below.
[image]

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried printing it in your views?

Comment: No I hadn't, but just did and I tried to figure the print part out but keep getting a block template error.  Can you please provide a print example I could try?

Comment: I mean add a `print total_sessions` in your `views.py` file.

Comment: Ok, so now I feel like a clown. I had `{{ total_sessions }}` inside my `for` loop.  Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the tag is not placed inside your loop.  I had `{{ total_sessions }}` inside my `for` loop.